# How to fix MySQL replication when duplicated key problem appears?

Tags: mysql, replication, recovery

I have data logger software that writes data to master database. There are just 2 tables. If this database is locked or stopped for more than 1 minute I will loose some data that should be stored.

Master database is replicated to another machine via cellular connection which is not stable sometimes. Replica is used to see the data on Grafana. It can be stopped for a long time and nothing bad will happen.

I have experienced [duplicated key problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323061/mysql-replication-over-unreliable-network) second time and I'm looking for productive way of fixing it. Last time it took me some time to find a way to fix it and the master database was locked for a few minutes because I couldn't do it properly and made several attempts.

I think I can just lock master database for a moment, execute mysql dump, check current log position, unlock it and start rebuilding my slave database.

I don't know exactly how I should rebuild the slave from master dump file. Should I truncate or remove tables from the slave? What about users and permissions?

Could someone please explain step by step how should I do it?

---

Here is my create table from the replica (created from master dump, so DDL is the same):

```
CREATE TABLE `bits` (
  `Id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `B01` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B02` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B03` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B04` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B05` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B06` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B07` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B08` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B09` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B10` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B11` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B12` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B13` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B14` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B15` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B16` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B17` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `B18` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `idx_dt` (`Datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92553 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `Id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `W01` int NOT NULL,
  `W02` int NOT NULL,
  `W03` int NOT NULL,
  `W04` int NOT NULL,
  `W05` int NOT NULL,
  `W06` int NOT NULL,
  `W07` int NOT NULL,
  `W08` int NOT NULL,
  `W09` int NOT NULL,
  `W10` int NOT NULL,
  `W11` int NOT NULL,
  `W12` int NOT NULL,
  `W13` int NOT NULL,
  `W14` int NOT NULL,
  `W15` int NOT NULL,
  `W16` int NOT NULL,
  `W17` int NOT NULL,
  `W18` int NOT NULL,
  `W19` int NOT NULL,
  `W20` int NOT NULL,
  `W21` int NOT NULL,
  `W22` int NOT NULL,
  `W23` int NOT NULL,
  `W24` int NOT NULL,
  `W25` int NOT NULL,
  `W26` int NOT NULL,
  `W27` int NOT NULL,
  `W28` int NOT NULL,
  `W29` int NOT NULL,
  `W30` int NOT NULL,
  `W31` int NOT NULL,
  `W32` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `idx_dt` (`Datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92553 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

There are single primary keys in the tables (bigint Id).

There are no `INSERT` operation sources on the replica, except replication from master.

Here is the log tail from my replica:

```
2023-02-14T09:48:00.884440Z 161 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error reconnecting to master 'replica@10.15.0.12:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.15.0.12:3306' (110), Error_code: MY-002003
2023-02-21T13:13:38.933590Z 161 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error reconnecting to master 'replica@10.15.0.12:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.15.0.12:3306' (110), Error_code: MY-002003
2023-02-27T01:05:20.054098Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave SQL for channel '': Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log NBMS-DELL-bin.000009, end_log_pos 8885352; Could not execute Write_rows event on table nbmslogger.bits; Duplicate entry '91393' for key 'bits.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 8885352, Error_code: MY-001062
2023-02-27T11:58:07.334955Z 37 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave SQL for channel '': Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log NBMS-DELL-bin.000009, end_log_pos 8885352; Could not execute Write_rows event on table nbmslogger.bits; Duplicate entry '91393' for key 'bits.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 8885352, Error_code: MY-001062
```

When I open that table in DBeaver I see that there are more records replicated from the master, but replication will probably try to insert them again for some reason.

Comment: Regarding samples: There are just two simple inserts, one for each table. Data is being inserted by Entity Framework-based application. I have no SQL. Keys are generated automtically (at least I'm not providing Id field for Entity Framework object).

Comment: This is indeed kind of 1:1 relationship. It is split because `bits` data comes from one read from industrial PLC and `words` data comes from second `read` operation from industrial PLC. I cannot read bits and words from PLC in one Modbus communication transaction, so the database has separate tables.

Comment: @RickJames Why should I drop unique keys? I will get duplicated records when it will happen again?

Comment: The PK serves _all_ the functionality of `UNIQUE`. You _could_ set the columns to `NULL` first, then `UPDATE` them when the new data comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not have two tables that share the same `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  Instead, insert into one table *with* an `AUTO_INCREMENT`,  get the id from that table (using, for example, `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) for the other table that does *not* have `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Better yet, combine the two tables into a single table.

Also:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY (id)  -- This is redundant, DROP it.
```

Comment: This schema has been generated by Entity Framework. Now I understand. It looks like something is wrong in Entity Framework.

Comment: I should drop it on the master database, and this operation will replicate to my replica, right?

Comment: Usually, I spend my time here 'working around' issues with frameworks; this sounds like a case where it is blatantly wrong.  Yes, perform the `ALTER TABLE .. DROP INDEX ..` on the Primary; it will replicate automatically.  I do not know how long each DROP will take; the table could be blocked for some time.

Comment: Thank you for good suggestion. I think it will execute in few seconds, master machine is pretty fast and there are just around 90k records in each table. I have not read framework manual. Maybe I did something wrong while defining my entities. I will investigate this later. I marked your answer as accepted, however I cannot test if the problem is solved by dropping that redundant index.

Comment: I have checked sources of application with Entity Framework to see if I have not done some weird stuff with Id field there. I didn't. I have something like this `public long Id { get; set; }` without extra code involved. So it must be one of many Entity Framework+MySQL issues.

Comment: The two `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids _may not_ track each other forever.  Regardless of whether it is causing the original problem, it _will_ cause you other grief.  Dropping the Unique is unlikely to fix anything.  I am recommending both things at least as first steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do a quick fix.

On my replica I just removed >=91393 records from my `bits` table.

Then I have stopped replica (`stop replica;`) and started it again (`start replica;`). After this new error in mysql logs appeared. It was about duplicated keys in second, `words` table. I removed rows again, like in first table.

But still it is a mystery why it happens...

Comment: Do they have matching `ids`?

Comment: Yes. Everything was the same. It looked like there was a successful replication and suddenly it "forgot" that it was done and it tries to insert these records again. After this operation I see that data is correct (I would see that the chart is not continuous).